# transform-to-json -- custom config drops elements? no array?

Tags: marklogic

I have the following xml

```
<foods
  xmlns="http://example.com/agt"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
  <food id="1" name="celery">
    <price>50.2</price>
  </food>
  <food id="2" name="beets">
    <price>23.3</price>
  </food>
  <food id="3" name="goat cheese">
    <price>0.5</price>
  </food>
</foods>
```

With the following xsd:

```
<xs:schema
  targetNamespace="http://example.com/agt"
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
  elementFormDefault="unqualified"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
  <xs:element name="food">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="price"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="foods">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="food" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

When I execute the following query in the console:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace json = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json" at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";
declare namespace agt = "http://example.com/agt";
let   $c := json:config("custom")
      , $_ := map:put($c,"array-element-names", "food")
return
  json:transform-to-json( doc("foods.xml") , $c )
```

... I get:

```
{"foods":{"food":{"id":3, "name":"goat cheese", "price":0.5}}}
```

Something isn't clicking for me.  What happened to the food elements?  No array, and only the last one made it into the output.  Note that taking out the array-element-names does *not* solve the missing food elements.

Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong?  I just started with MarkLogic Server, so I could very well be doing it wrong. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to indicate that food is an array element.
Since you have now put food in a namespace your array-element-names isnt finding it.
You either need to use an xs:QName() to give the full name of "food" or to declare the default namespace for the configuration using

e.g. this should work

```
  , $_ := map:put($c,"array-element-names", xs:QName("agt:food") )
```

alternatively

```
   , $_ := map:put($c,"element-namespace","http://example.com/agt")
```

which has the nice side effect of making the transformation reversible.

Comment: Thanks!  I missed the namespace issue altogether.  For those interested, this discussion carried on in the [Marklogic mailing list](http://marklogic.markmail.org/search/?q=#query:+page:2+mid:wgbhvi3ex4kbhl3b+state:results).